# Does LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock resultrows or whole table?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

After searching for a while I gave up because I couldn't find this answer anywhere so I'm trying here.

I'm using Spring Boot and CrudRepository for fetching entities from my oracle database.
However I'm not sure if this code, called inside a `@Transaction`, will lock my whole table or simply just the result entities returned by `findAllByStatusAndCreatedBetween`?

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    List<MyEntity> findAllByStatusAndCreatedBetween(Status status, Date from, Date to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE internally executes select for update statement.

SELECT FOR UPDATE locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows. Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels. Consistent reads ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view. (Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they are reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)

Please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/innodb-locking-reads.html